# What is the importance of constructors that creating in a same class?

Tags: java, constructor

I am very new to Java. I know the basic concepts of constructors. I know that, if we don't create any constructor also compiler will create default constructor.

I have created a program to check how this toString() method is usable,

```
public class Vehicle{
    int rollNo;
    String name;
    int age;
    public Vehicle(int rollNo, String name, int age){
        this.rollNo=rollNo;
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return rollNo+""+name+""+age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle v=new Vehicle(100, "XXX", 23);
        Vehicle v2=new Vehicle(101, "XXXS", 24);

        System.out.println(v);
        System.out.println(v2);
    }
}
```

And, I am getting output as :

```
   100XXX23
   101XXXS24
```

But, my doubt is why are we creating constructor and passing same variables as arguments to that?

Why can't we assign the values to variables like this and can't we get values without constructor?

```
public class Vehicle{
    int rollNo=100;
    String name="XXX";
    int age=23;
    // public Vehicle(int rollNo, String name, int age){
    //     this.rollNo=rollNo;
    //     this.name=name;
    //     this.age=age;
    // }
    // 


    public static void main(String[] args){
      //  Vehicle v=new Vehicle(100, "XXX", 23);
    //    Vehicle v2=new Vehicle(101, "XXXS", 24);

            Vehicle v=new Vehicle(rollno,name,age);
         //   Vehicle v2=new Vehicle();



        System.out.println(v);
      //  System.out.println(v2);
    }

     public String toString(){
        return rollNo+""+name+""+age;
    }
}
```

Comment: you might read this article about encapsulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: The benefit of creating constructors that take arguments is actually that you can have many objects of the same class that has different attribute values. for example if we have a Car class that has instuctor that takes the amount of fuel (int) as an argument we might create two Car objects with different amount of fuel for example Car firstCar = new Car(20); and Car secondCar = new Car(30);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it is possible to set the values of attributes or properties without a defined constructor in the class definition. This can be done through the use of setters on the attributes/properties within a Java class. So for example:

```
public class Vehicle{
    int rollNo;
    String name;
    int age;

    // Note no constructor, so the default no-arg constructor can be used. 

    // Now the setters
    public void setRollNo(int anInt) {
        this.rollNo = anInt;
    }

    public String setName(String aName) {
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public void setAge(int anAge) {
        this.age = anAge;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle v=new Vehicle(); // note no-arg constructor being used.
        v.setRollNo(3);
        v.setName("Hello");
        v.setAge(12);
        System.out.println(v);
    }

}
```

The use of setters is far better as you adhere to an important OOP principle; that of encapsulation, which in Java and Software is quite critical.

Please have a look at the following [Java Tutorial from Oracle that goes through the use of getters and setters and the use of constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is declared `static`, which means that it doesn't belong to any particular copy of your class. If you want to create copies of the class to use for whatever purpose, you use `new`, which causes the constructor to build a copy for you, and in your case set the appropriate variables (which belong to particular copies of the class, like the copies that you're holding in the `v` and `v2` variables).

The fact that the `main` method is part of the same class is essentially irrelevant; `main` could be attached to any class, even an otherwise empty one.

Comment: this is true but this does not answer his question at all.

Comment: @PhilippSander It's unclear what exactly the question is, and my answer is targeted at the uncertainty the example code shows.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have to use Constructor having arguments is that created instance is immutable objects which means that whose state cannot be modified after it is created. In other words object does not have setter it only has getter methods.

In java platform GC is the main part of JVM, and immutable objects makes GS less work to clean the unusable objects in heap memory.

Pls refer to link http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ImmutableObjectsAndGarbageCollection

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor from the compiler will be the following.

```
public Vehicle()
```

If you don't define

```
public Vehicle(int rollNo, String name, int age)
```

then it won't exist and you can't use it.

Java does not create default constructors with arguments.